# How to do candlestick without all parameters

Tags: python, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

So I'm trying to create a candlestick graph, the dict I get from the site is something like this:

```
    {
        "Id" : 319435,
        "TimeStamp" : "2014-07-09T03:21:20.08",
        "Quantity" : 0.30802438,
        "Price" : 0.01263400,
        "Total" : 0.00389158,
        "FillType" : "FILL",
        "OrderType" : "BUY"
    }
```

The thing is, for the candlestick using all those matplotlib stuff to work, it needs some parameters I don't have
I think it uses Date, Open, Close, High, Low and Volume

What are my options here?

Comment: A candlestick is **defined** as a plot showing Open, Close, High, Low. If you don't have that data, you probably want to plot something else. But who know what that would be? Well, you know! So if you tell us how the plot should look like, you might get help here. If you then also provide some sample data, such that we have a [mcve] of what you have tried, you can be sure to get an answer quite soon.

Comment: I usually try to put some more code in, but I don't have much. I think I need more of information like you just did instead of code. You see, I only have that much info from the site so if a candlestick is not possible, what could I do using those infos (Price, Total and then x axis = timestamp?) is it possible to use more than one parameter for the y axis on a normal graph with matplotlib? I thought a candlestick would be nice because of 'Total' (volume of buy/sell from each order)

Comment: I don't know what total is. But yes, you can plot several datasets into the same axes with matplotlib. There are enough examples around on how to do that.

Comment: Total is how much, in the currency I'm using, the order costed. I tried doing a graph with only price and timestamp but it doesn't look good. [link](https://i.imgur.com/HmguhXu.png) I'll try looking at how to put more parameters in with price for Y axis and then if I need help I'll try to formulate it better then

Comment: I think the figure produced looks reasonable. You should indeed get a clear picture on what to ask before posting a question here.